# Timeout when loading Home Page, correctly load other pages in front or admin

Tags: homepage

My website is accessible on every page (including back-office) except home, raising a timeout error in the browser.

Timeout : https://uneimagevautmillemots.fr/
Works : https://www.uneimagevautmillemots.fr/les-titres-de-presse-aides-en-2015/

The theme is set to wordpress defaut one and plugins have been disabled.

Any idea ?

Comment: You appear to have numerous plugins installed, but if the only symptom is a timeout then that just isn't enough information to diagnose the problem. Deactivate everything then turn it back on 1 by 1 to identify the culprit, otherwise, you'll need to provide a significant amount of information for this to be answerable

Comment: No, all plugins are disabled

Comment: If I open the working page, I see that the link to the homepage is `https://www.uneimagevautmillemots.fr/`, which also works (only with the www).
Look into your WP settings and also your htaccess file.

Comment: Both settings fields are set to `https://www.uneimagevautmillemots.fr` in backoffice, and `.htaccess` is the one generated by wordpress, no domain name inside.